# a question about complex number addition

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\omega $ be a ($2^n-1$)$^{th}$ root of unity, where n is an even number. What is the value of :
$$\omega +\omega ^2+\omega ^4+\omega ^8+..\omega ^{2^{n-1}} ; ~~
(\omega \ne 1 )$$
This question seems really simple but I really have a difficulty to start on this. Can anyone help?
I actually hope that this value will equal to 1 since it will help me to proceed faster.

Comment: If $\omega=1$ then this is clear.  I'm not fully sure on the other roots.

Comment: oops I think $w=1$ is not ok here

Comment: I think w can only equal to complex root that contain complex number. Thank you though

Comment: I think you mean a primitive $(2^{n}-1)$'th root of unity.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any obvious pattern to the results, nor any reason why the answer would be nice. From computation you can see that the answer is definitely not 1.

Comment: Take $n=2$ as a test case?

Comment: Actually I am not sure about this. I tested and find I failed...

Comment: Wait.  So $w^k = 2^n - 1$ for some $k$.  Well, to what degree is $w$ a root of k.  If $w = \sqrt[2]{2^n-1}$ is going to be a completely different answer than $w= \sqrt[537]{2^n-1}$.  Are you sure you stated the question right?  Did you mean $w^n = 1$ but $w$ is a primitive root?

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything I strongly believe you meant what I have edited in first line.Give confirmation.

Comment: Yeah.... I don't think there is any such thing as a "root of unity of 63" or a "root of unity of 255".

Comment: I think you mean "$w$ is a $2^n -1$ degree root of unity".  Which means $w^{2^n -1} = 1$ and $w^k \ne 1$ for any $k < 2^n - 1$.

Comment: @fleablood Yes it is, edit was accepted.

Comment: sorry I actually didn't check the edit. I think it should be primitive $"2^n-1"th$ root of unity

Comment: I  am so sorry guys I think I did the last step wrong and got the wrong initial condition. So can you check the new edit and maybe that will help?

Answer (score 1):

For example, I plotted the results for the case $n=6$:

[image]

and $n=8$:

[image]

What's going on here is that you're taking $2^n-1$ points on the parametric curves $z + z^2 + \ldots + z^{2^{n/2}}$, $z = e^{i\theta}$.  In the case $n=8$ that curve looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There were misleading edits  to the question at one point, can you annotate what formula/relationship your lovely curves are from?

Comment: ... This looks pretty messed up but still a big thank you . Btw Can you check my edits and see if that help at all? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using all $(2^{n}-1)$'th roots of unity $\omega$ except $1$ here, and plotting $\sum_{j=0}^{n/2} \omega^{2^j}$

Comment: maybe change the n/2 to n-1?